# How to subclass concurency control in spring, and what exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, session-management

Right now in Spring security I have this code:

```
<session-management>
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
</session-management>
```

If someone attempts to start a concurrent session, an exception is thrown.  The way my application handles exceptions is by catching them and then throwing a custom exception that will be displayed to the user.
My question is two-part.

First, and most importantly, how do I create a custom class that can be given to session management so that it can catch the old exception and throw the new?  It seems to me that I need to subclass concurrency-control, and make a bean of some sort within my security context, but I am not sure how to do that.

Second, what is the name of the exception that will be thrown (the one I need to catch)? My guess is that it will be an AccessDeniedException, but I am unsure.  This is not as important as the first question, because once I know the correct class I must subclass, I will know what exceptions it could be.

Thanks for the help,

MirroredFate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... I have found my answer.

I subclassed `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`, and over-rode the method `allowableSessionsExceeded`.  This method throws a `SessionAuthenticationException`, who's message I changed before throwing it again. I had to add this code:

```
<security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="ccc"/>

<beans:bean id="ccc"
    class="com.lim.lds.client.sqlloader.security.CustomConcurrencyControl">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
        ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

to my `spring-security.xml` file.

I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation!